# 135149 is all info I have

Tags: set-identification

My son got some LEGO bricks in a bag as a present from good will, but no instructions were included. The only info I have are numbers on the bag 135149 and 2011. One of the small pieces has 62361. But no luck to have any info with numbers.

Comment: The numbers on the bags don't give us much to go on.  Can you add a picture or two?

Comment: People on this stack can literally identify a set from a picture of the parts. It's crazy. But you should post a picture so they can work their magic.

Answer (score 2):

2011 is probably just the year the bag was copyrighted, not anything useable to go on.

The other number on the bag is not really useable either.

Part 62361 is [Vehicle, Mudguard 1 1/2 x 6 x 1 with Arch](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=62361&name=Vehicle,%20Mudguard%201%201/2%20x%206%20x%201%20with%20Arch&category=%5BVehicle,%20Mudguard%5D#T=P) a part that has been in 98 sets. There are probably numbers on most other parts in the bag too, but pictures are usually better.